# Why are non-Schengen countries excluded from the Covid-19 US travel ban?

Tags: united-states, european-union, immigration, covid-19, schengen-area

The US government [suspended travel from Europe to US](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-51846923), except for countries which are not in the Schengen area such as the UK and Ireland.

Many comments from EU leader seem to assume that this is a political decision rather than a health-based decision, especially with regard to this exception.

Is there any official rationale for this exception?

Comment: Is the immigration tag appropriate? This question covers people going on holiday or attending business meetings much more so that those migrating.

Comment: I have removed the immigration tag since it is clearly a travel ban not related to immigration.

Comment: @Jontia even visitors and other travelers who are not migrating pass through immigration control.  This sense of the word does not seem to fall under the definition of the [tag:immigration] tag here at [Politics.SE], however.

Comment: @Alexei it does apply to immigrants to the US who haven't yet entered for the first time, because they are not yet permanent residents.  If they've been in the Schengen area, they will have to find somewhere else to wait for two weeks before arriving in the US.

Comment: @phoog - yes, but if I got it right they are treated as regular travelers coming from Schengen area: "The ban applies to travellers.... US citizens are also exempt.". Their immigrant status does not seem to matter here.

Comment: @Alexei permanent residents of the US are also excluded from the ban (Section 2(a)(i)).  I'm just pointing out that someone with an immigrant visa who hasn't yet reached the US is not yet a permanent resident and therefore would not benefit from that exclusion.  Therefore, there is in fact an effect on US immigration (in the sense of the tag).

Comment: Today the travel ban was extended to the UK.

Comment: The UK and Ireland [have just been included](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-51891662) in the US ban, so this question is fairly overtaken by events. @Jontia: regarding the "immigration" tag: I added it because we don't have a [border-controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_control) tag proper (the 'borders' tag seemed even less suitable). I agree that immigration usually refers to more than mere tourism travel. I actually wanted to bring up the issue on meta (whether we should have a border-controls tag), but was really busy this past week[end].

Comment: @Jontia: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/should-we-have-a-separate-tag-for-border-controls-or-maybe-one-for-travel-bans

Comment: @phoog: : https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/should-we-have-a-separate-tag-for-border-controls-or-maybe-one-for-travel-bans

Comment: @Alexei: : https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/should-we-have-a-separate-tag-for-border-controls-or-maybe-one-for-travel-bans

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The official rationale, according to Trump's [presidential proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/), is that the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) could become overwhelmed "if sustained human-to-human transmission of the virus occurred in the United States on a large scale". It continues:

> The World Health Organization has determined that multiple countries
>   within the Schengen Area are experiencing sustained person-to-person
>   transmission of SARS-CoV-2.
>
> [...]
>
> The Schengen Area currently has the largest number of confirmed
>   COVID-19 cases outside of the People’s Republic of China.  As of March
>   11, 2020, the number of cases in the 26 Schengen Area countries is
>   17,442, with 711 deaths, and shows high continuous growth in infection
>   rates.  In total, as of March 9, 2020, the Schengen Area has exported
>   201 COVID-19 cases to 53 countries.  Moreover, the free flow of people
>   between the Schengen Area countries makes the task of managing the
>   spread of the virus difficult.
>
> The United States Government is unable to effectively evaluate and
>   monitor all of the travelers continuing to arrive from the Schengen
>   Area.  The potential for undetected transmission of the virus by
>   infected individuals seeking to enter the United States from the
>   Schengen Area threatens the security of our transportation system and
>   infrastructure and the national security.  Given the importance of
>   protecting persons within the United States from the threat of this
>   harmful communicable disease, I have determined that it is in the
>   interests of the United States to take action to restrict and suspend
>   the entry into the United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, of
>   all aliens who were physically present within the Schengen Area during
>   the 14-day period preceding their entry or attempted entry into the
>   United States.

The reasoning exposed in the proclamation, then, is that due to the lack of travel restrictions between Schengen countries, it is far harder to manage the spread of the disease by controlling inter-Schengen migration. This factor is attributed by the proclamation as the main cause of community spread throughout the 26 member countries, and even goes as far as to tacitly blame the international spread of the disease on the area.

At a practical level, consider someone arriving to the USA from Slovenia, a member of the Schengen area. While Slovenia itself only has 31 cases [currently](https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200311-sitrep-51-covid-19.pdf), it is impossible for USA immigration officials to tell whether that person has just driven from Italy, which has over 10,000 cases. As a result, the Trump administration seems to have decided that the best way to deal with this issue is a blanket ban (with some exceptions, e.g. US citizens, travellers invited by the US to aid efforts against Covid-19 etc. See proclamation for full details) on travel from the Schengen area countries and visitors who have visited the area within the last 14 days, the incubation period of the disease.

Travellers from a non-Schengen area, however, seem to be presumed to be able to prove that they haven't been in any Schengen countries in the last 14 days by their passport records, and as such the level of risk they pose should be able to  be more easily evaluated.

However, as pointed out in the comments, inter-European travel does not involve passport stamping in some cases, for example from Italy to the UK, so it will be difficult to identify these travellers practically. It is unclear how immigration officials will mitigate this.

The reasoning of the proclamation, however, remains that travel restrictions *could* be easily imposed between, to use our example, Italy and the UK, meaning that travellers from the UK are lower risk.

*Update 14/03*: The travel ban has now been extended to the UK and Ireland, which calls into question the original official rationale, but does not change it.

Comment: Comments deleted. This comment section is not for debating the pro's and con's of travel restrictions.

Comment: `Travellers from a non-Schengen area, however, seem to be presumed to be able to prove that they haven't been in any Schengen countries in the last 14 days by their passport records` Not necessarily. I am in the UK. Last week I was in France, there is nothing on my passport that shows this (unless this is recorded electronically somewhere?)

Comment: @Rodney did you show the passport at the port of entry? I think there's a record kept of people entering and leaving the schengen area, due to the treaty.

Comment: This answer seems to blur the line between travel *records* and travel *restrictions*. In the example of Slovenia you give, for instance, there [now *are* travel restrictions](http://www.sloveniatimes.com/slovenia-closing-border-with-italy-as-coronavirus-cases-rise-to-34) preventing people entering from Italy. It's harder under Schengen rules to impose restrictions based on *past* travel history but specific new movements *can* still be stopped.

Comment: @bobsburner there is no system keeping records of entries to and exits from Schengen area.  Such a system is [in development](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32017R2226), but it will not keep records of the entries and exits of EU citizens nor of others who benefit from EU free movement law.

Comment: @Rodney the UK might keep such a record, but there is no Schengen-wide system.  See my previous comment for more detail.  (I do not know whether individual Schengen countries keep records unilaterally, so as far as I know it is possible that France has a record of your departure, or, if you flew through another Schengen country, that country might have it.)

Comment: @bobsburner yes I showed my passport in both directions, question is, is that record available to US border control?

Comment: And they probably would like to be able to exclude even U.S. citizens travelling from the Schengen area, were it not for the fact that a U.S. citizen _cannot_ legally be denied entry to the United States.

Comment: *"While Slovenia itself only has 31 cases currently, it is impossible for USA immigration officials to tell whether that person has just driven from Italy,"* - as a matter of fact, many of the borders within the EU, especially towards Italy, are currently closed and you **can't** just drive over from Italy.